# Mongokit schema index on fields in array

Tags: mongodb, mongokit

How do I create index on items.id field in this mongokit schema?
I tried to creating index on items.id, but it's throwing `ValueError: Error in indexes: can't find items.id in structure`.

```
structure = {
   'items': [{
        'id': int,
    }]
}

indexes = [{   
    'fields': ['items.id'],
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, MongoKit's index validation doesn't support validation on indexed array. For this usecase, you have disabled indexes validation:

```
indexes = [
  {'fields': ['items.id'], 'check':False}
]
```

you can vote on this issue here : http://github.com/namlook/mongokit/issues#issue/42